# Azure SQL Server: Insert 20m records between tables is slow (60+ mins)

Tags: sql-server, azure, performance, azure-sql-database, sql-insert

I've been going through the boards and tried lots of different things without luck. So thought id reach out to the community directly.

**The problem:**
I have an Azure SQL Server DB that has 2 tables:

- DATA_IMPORT (Source table I import data into via Data Factory...it gets truncated each load (approx 20m rows).
- DATA_SOURCE (Table where I insert the 20m rows from DATA_IMPORT into with some simple transformation.  This is expected to reach about 0.5b rows)

Im a little new to SQL Server and now resorted to having no indexes in DATA_SOURCE to see if that helps....still takes 60+mins.
No indexes are needed on table DATA_IMPORT, since its just a holding table.

**Table Structures**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DATA_IMPORT ](

    [field1]    [nvarchar](255)     NOT NULL,
    [field2]    [nvarchar](255)     NOT NULL,
    [field3]    [nvarchar](255)     NOT NULL,
    [field4]    [nvarchar](255)     NOT NULL,
    [field5]    [nvarchar](255)     NOT NULL,
    [field6]    [nvarchar](255)     NOT NULL,
    [field7]    [nvarchar](255)     NOT NULL,
    [field8]    [nvarchar](255)     NOT NULL,
    [field9]    [nvarchar](255)     NOT NULL,
    [field10]   [nvarchar](255)     NOT NULL,
    [measure1]  int                 NULL,
    [measure2]  decimal(10,2)       NULL,
    [measure3]  decimal(10,5)       NULL,
    [measure4]  decimal(7,2)        NULL,
    [measure5]  decimal(10,5)       NULL                                                        
) 


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DATA_SOURCE](
   
    [EFF_DATE]      [datetime]       NOT NULL,
    [EFF_STATUS]    [nvarchar](255)  NOT NULL,
    [DATA_SOURCE]   [nvarchar](255)  NOT NULL,
    [PERIOD]        [date]           NOT NULL,

    [field1]    [nvarchar](255)     NOT NULL,
    [field2]    [nvarchar](255)     NOT NULL,
    [field3]    [nvarchar](255)     NOT NULL,
    [field4]    [nvarchar](255)     NOT NULL,
    [field5]    [nvarchar](255)     NOT NULL,
    [field6]    [nvarchar](255)     NOT NULL,
    [field7]    [nvarchar](255)     NOT NULL,
    [field8]    [nvarchar](255)     NOT NULL,
    [field9]    [nvarchar](255)     NOT NULL,
    [field10]   [nvarchar](255)     NOT NULL,
    [measure1]  int                 NULL,
    [measure2]  decimal(10,2)       NULL,
    [measure3]  decimal(10,5)       NULL,
    [measure4]  decimal(7,2)        NULL,
    [measure5]  decimal(10,5)       NULL,
    [measure6]  decimal(11,3)       NULL

    [REC_CREATEDBY]             [nvarchar](50)      NOT NULL,
    [REC_CREATEDON]             [datetime]          NOT NULL,
    [REC_LASTUPDATEDBY]         [nvarchar](50)      NULL,
    [REC_LASTUPDATEDON]         [datetime]          NULL
 
)
```

**INSERT SQL**

```
--YYYY-MM-DD
Declare @varPeriod varchar(30) = '2020-01-01'
Declare @varDataSource varchar(255) = 'https://blah.com'

INSERT INTO [DATA_SOURCE] (
            [EFF_DATE],[EFF_STATUS],[DATA_SOURCE],[PERIOD],

            [field1],[field2],[field3],[field4],[field5],
            [field6],[field7],[field8],[field9],[field10],
            [measure1],[measure2],[measure3],[measure4],[measure5],
            [measure6],

            [REC_CREATEDBY],[REC_CREATEDON], [REC_LASTUPDATEDBY], [REC_LASTUPDATEDON])

SELECT  
     
      SYSDATETIME()                     AS [EFF_DATE]
      ,'A'                                  AS [EFF_STATUS]
      ,@varDataSource                       AS [DATA_SOURCE],
      CONVERT(varchar, @varPeriod, 100)     AS [PERIOD],

      [field1],[field2],[field3],[field4],[field5],
      [field6],[field7],[field8],[field9],[field10],
      [measure1],[measure2],[measure3],[measure4],[measure5],
      ,CAST([measure1]*[measure2] AS numeric(11,3)) as [measure6]

      ,'DATA_LOADER'                AS [REC_CREATEDBY]
      ,SYSDATETIME()                AS [REC_CREATEDON]
      ,'DATA_LOADER'                AS [REC_LASTUPDATEDBY]
      ,SYSDATETIME()                AS [REC_LASTUPDATEDON]    
  FROM [dbo].[DATA_IMPORT];
 GO
```

What performance recommendations do you have so I can insert these 20m rows quickly?
I will need to apply a 3/4 indexes too once I join to my dimensional data.

Thanks for your help all
Jay

Comment: Could you [share the execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) ? And what SKU/pricing tier is your Azure Database currently running ?

Comment: Also try `INSERT INTO [DATA_SOURCE] (...) WITH (TABLOCK)` To enable table lock.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: use BULK Insert for a better performance when inserting data.

PS: another important thing to look is the DTU / vCores you assign to your database.

Comment: Hi Thiago - Thanks for the help, is there a way to prevent the transaction logs from being created?  And do you feel its the Convert() / Cast functions that are the problem?  I can always transform the target post INSERT.

Comment: @Thiago, minimal logging to transaction log is automaticlay enabled since SQL Server 2016. See [traceflag 610](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-traceon-trace-flags-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: @Preben Huybrechts: your statement is unclear; minimal logging is NOT turned on by default.

Comment: @Thiago, from the documentation: "Controls minimally logged inserts into indexed tables. This trace flag is not required starting SQL Server 2016 as minimal logging is turned on by default for indexed tables. In SQL Server 2016 (13.x), when the bulk load operation causes a new page to be allocated, all of the rows sequentially filling that new page are minimally logged if all the other pre-requisites for minimal logging are met. Rows inserted into existing pages (no new page allocation) to maintain index order are still fully logged, ... "

Comment: you're right, insert into also allow minimal log. I'll edit my answer